# CSS drop-down menu displays horizontally instead of vertical

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

**

```css
body 
{
 
  background-color: #9cb4c0;
  
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
 
.div-1
{
  float: right;
 
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
 
h2
{ 
  text-align: right;
}
 
h3
{
  
  text-align: left;
  
  color: white;
}
 
a:link
{
  
  color: rgb(7, 19, 86);
    
  background-color: transparent;
    
  text-decoration: none;
  
  font-size: 20px;
}

a:visited 
{
    
  color: orange;
    
  background-color: transparent;
    
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
a:active
{
    
  color: rgb(216, 120, 10);
    
  background-color: transparent;
    
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.list-1 
{
    
  list-style-type: none;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  
  margin: 0;
  
  padding: 0;
  
  text-align : right;
}

.list-1:active
{
 box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
 
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
 
.list-1 li  a
{
  
  float: right;

  display: block;
  
  padding: 8px;
  
  text-align: center;
  
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  
  color: #666;
}
 
.list-1 li a:hover 
{
  background-color: #ff6c00;
}
 
.list-2 
{
 
  list-style-type: none;
  
  margin: 0;
  
  padding: 0;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  
  background-color: #228bbb;
}
 
.list-2 a 
{
  
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;

  float: left;
  
  display: block;
  
  padding: 14px 16px;  
  
  color: rgb(7, 19, 86);
}
 
.drop-button 
{
  
   display: inline-block;
   
   text-align: center;
   
   padding: 16px;
   
   border: none;
   
   cursor: pointer;
}
 
.dropdown 
{
  
  display: block;
  
  margin: 0;
  
  padding: 0;
}
 
.dropdown-content 
{
 
  display: none;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  
  min-width: 160px;
  
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
 
.dropdown-content a 
{
 
  color: black;
  
  padding: 12px 16px;
  
  text-decoration: none;
  
  display: block;
  
  text-align: left;
}
 
.dropdown-content a:hover 
{
 
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
 
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content 
{
 
  display: inline-block;
}
 
.list-2 a:hover:not(.active) 
{
  
  background-color: #ff6c00;
}
 
.list-2 .active 
{
    
  background-color: #ff6c00;
}

.list-3 
{
 
  color: rgb(7, 19, 86);
  
  list-style-type: disk;
}
 
.list-4 
{
  
  color: rgb(9, 91, 130);
  
  list-style-type: disk;
  
  font-size: 20px;
}

.div-2Dropdown
{
  position: relative;
  
  display: inline-block;
}
 
.div-2Dropdown-content
{
  display: none;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  
  min-width: 160px;
  
  box-shadow: opx 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  
  z-index: 1;
}

.div-2Dropdown:hover .div-2Dropdown-content
{
  display: block;
}
 
.desc
{
 padding: 3px;
 
 text-align: center;
}
 
table
{
   
   float: left;
   
   padding: 10px;
   
   border: 10px;
   
   border-color: rgb(7, 15, 79);
   
   margin: 10px;
   
   border-width: 2px;  
    
   border-style: groove;
}
 
.button 
{
   background-color: #2980B9;
   
   color: white;
   
   font-family: arial;
   
   border: none;
   
   padding: 10px 10px;
   
   text-align: center;
   
   display: inline-block;
   
   margin: 4px 2px;
   
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
   
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   
   cursor: pointer;
   
   font-style: italic;
   
   outline: none;
   
   box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

.button:hover
{
 background-color: #2980B9;
 
 border: 2px solid #2980B9;
 
 box-shadow: 0px 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

.button:active
{
 background-color: #2980B9;
 
 box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
 
 transform: translateY(4px);
}
 
footer 
{
   
   clear: both;
    
   position: relative;
    
   z-index: 10;
    
   height: 1em;
    
   margin-top: -3em;
   
   text-align: center;
   
   background-color: #228bbb;
   
   color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

<title> SLIIT LIBRARY </title>

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Style.css" />

</head>

<body>

<img src = "SLIIT.png" width = "300" height = "200">

<div class = "div-1">

<ul class = "list-1">

 <li> <a href = "/Login/" target = "_blank"> Login </a> 
 
  <a href = "Login to the system.html" target = "_blank"> Register </a>
 </li>

</ul>

<h2> <a href = "/SLIIT LIBRARY/" target = "_blank"> SLIIT LIBRARY </h2> </a>

</div>

<ul class = "list-2">
 <li> <a href = "/Home/" target = "_blank"> Home </a> </li>
 <li style = "float : right"> <a class = "active" href = "/About Us/" target = "_blank"> About Us</a> </li>
 <li> <a href = "/Membership/" target = "_blank"> Membership </a> </li>
 <li> <a href = "/Staff/" target = "_blank"> Staff </a> </li>
 <li> <a href = "/Search/" target = "_blank"> Search </a> </li> 
 <li class = "dropdown"> <a href = "javascript:void(0)" class = "drop-button"> New Arrivals </button> </a>
  <div class = "dropdown-content">
   <a href = "/Books/"  target = "_blank"> Books </a>
   <a href = "/Magazines/"  target = "_blank"> Magazines </a>
   <a href = "/News Papers/"  target = "_blank"> News Papers </a>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>

<div style = "float : left ; background-color : #39a2d2 ; width : 300px ; height : 950px ; margin : auto ; margin-right : 2em">

</body>

</html>
```

**I've tried over and over to overcome the issue but I couldn't find a solution for this. Any ideas to fix the drop-down menu to it's vertical display? Plus "a:visited" also isn't working. How to fix this?

Here's my CSS code;

a:visited 
{

```
    color: orange;

    background-color: transparent;

    text-decoration: none;
```

}

.list-2 
{

```
    list-style-type: none;

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

    overflow: hidden;

    background-color: #228bbb;
```

.drop-button 
{

```
        display: inline-block;

        text-align: center;

        padding: 16px;

        border: none;

        cursor: pointer;
```

}

.dropdown 
{

```
    display: block;

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;
```

}

.dropdown-content 
{

```
    display: none;

    position: absolute;

    background-color: #f9f9f9;

    min-width: 160px;

    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

}

.dropdown-content a 
{

```
    color: black;

    padding: 12px 16px;

    text-decoration: none;

    display: block;

    text-align: left;
```

}

.dropdown-content a:hover 
{

```
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
```

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content 
{

```
    display: inline-block;
```

}

Here's my HTML code;

```
<ul class = "list-2">
<li> <a href = "/Home/" target = "_blank"> Home </a> </li>
<li style = "float : right"> <a class = "active" href = "/About Us/" target = "_blank"> About Us</a> </li>
<li> <a href = "/Membership/" target = "_blank"> Membership </a> </li>
<li> <a href = "/Staff/" target = "_blank"> Staff </a> </li>
<li> <a href = "/Search/" target = "_blank"> Search </a> </li> 
<li class = "dropdown"> <a href = "javascript:void(0)" class = "drop-button"> New Arrivals </button> </a>
    <div class = "dropdown-content">
        <a href = "/Books/"  target = "_blank"> Books </a>
        <a href = "/Magazines/"  target = "_blank"> Magazines </a>
        <a href = "/News Papers/"  target = "_blank"> News Papers </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi, I recommend you use a HTML/CSS snippet instead of just a code block. It will mean that you will be able to show us exactly what your code looks like to you, I've copied your code into codepen but am not sure that what I see is what it looks like to you because the Books/Magazines/News Papers links are always showing even when I'm not hovering over New Arrivals.

Comment: since I'm fairly new to here would you please explain me to how to do that HTML/CSS snippet thing? :/ @TripWire

Comment: Go to edit your question, along the top line of the editor where you can make your post bold/italic etc you should see a page icon with angular brackets <> if you click on this it will allow you to enter your HTML/CSS and preview it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have altered this codepen example to fit your means: https://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd

You will need to restyle the menu but it should function as you expect it to:

```css
ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width: 100%;
}

ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

.right-menu-item 
{
  float: right;
}

ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Membership</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">New Arrivals</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Magazines</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News Papers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="right-menu-item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm having a doubt on why you've created a class called "dir" in drop-down items. Why didn't you add it to the style sheet? :/ As I thought that the error will overcome by editing that part only, instead of editing the whole code :( As well these ul attribute change will affect to my whole code and all the format will go wrong. I'm finding a way to edit that drop-down without affecting other lists :( @TripWire

Comment: Sorry those classes can be removed, updated my code to reflect that, to avoid affecting your other code you just need to add an id to the top level div and alter the CSS to reference that id instead of ul but it should give you what you want if you play with ids/classes

Answer (score 0):

The way your HTML is structured makes it look wrong.
Try the following:

```
<ul class = "list-2">
  <li> <a href = "/Home/" target = "_blank"> Home </a> </li>
  <li style = "float : right"> <a class = "active" href = "/About Us/" target = "_blank"> About Us</a> </li>
  <li> <a href = "/Membership/" target = "_blank"> Membership </a> </li>
  <li> <a href = "/Staff/" target = "_blank"> Staff </a> </li>
  <li> <a href = "/Search/" target = "_blank"> Search </a> </li> 
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" class = "drop-button"> New Arrivals </a>
    <ul class="list-2 dropdown-content">
      <li><a href = "/Books/"  target = "_blank"> Books </a></li>
      <li><a href = "/Magazines/"  target = "_blank"> Magazines </a></li>
      <li><a href = "/News Papers/"  target = "_blank"> News Papers </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Make sure to follow the standards people mentioned on the comments the next time you post your code!